# After executing javascript function the rest of the code is skipped

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the document loads it executes the `checkseason()` function and then it ignores the rest of the code. Without `checkseason()` at load the code works correctly for some reason and I need to execute `checkseason()` at the beginning to apply validation rules to an input field.

```
$.mask.definitions['~'] = '[+-]';
$.mask.definitions['x'] = '[0-9]';
$.mask.definitions['*'] = '[-A-Za-z0-9._\\\/?&=~]';

function checkseason(){
  d = document.getElementById("season").value;

  $('#second_form').validate({
    rules: {
      patch: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 4,
        maxlength: 4,
        remote: {
          url: "../checkpatch.php",
          type: "post"
        }
      }
    },
    messages: {
      patch: {
        required: "Please enter patch version.",
        remote: "Patch with this number already exists."
      }
    },

  });


  $('select[name="season"]').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "newseasons") {
      $('input[name="patch"]').rules('add', {
        minlength: 4,
        maxlength: 4,
        messages: {
          minlength: "Please enter 3 numbers"
        }
      });
    } else if ($(this).val() == "oldseasons") {
      $('input[name="patch"]').rules('add', {
        minlength: 8,
        maxlength: 9,
        messages: {
          minlength: "Please enter 8 numbers"
        }
      });
    }
  });

  if(d==='newseasons'){
    $("#patch").mask("x.xx", {
      placeholder: ""
    });
  }
  else if(d==='oldseasons'){

    $("#patch").unmask();
    $("#patch").mask("?x.x.x.xxx", {
      placeholder: ""
    });
  }
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  checkseason();

  var config = {
    fillAll: true
  };

  document.forms["second_form"].oninput = function(e) {
    var champion = this["champion[]"];

    //Force into array
    if (champion[0] === undefined)
      champion = [this["champion[]"]];

    var reached = {
      valid: 0,
      unique: 0
    };

    var inputs = [].map.call(champion, function(n) {
      return n.value
    }).filter(function(n) {
      return n.length
    });

    var valid = [].every.call(champion, function(n, i) {
      n.setCustomValidity("");
      if (config.fillAll) return (reached.valid = i, champions.hasOwnProperty(n.value));
      else return n.value ? (
        reached.valid = i,
        champions.hasOwnProperty(n.value) > -1
        ) : true;
    });

    var unique = inputs.slice(0).sort().every(function(n, i, a) {
      reached.unique = inputs.lastIndexOf(n);
      return n != a[i - 1];
    });

    //Check for valid champions
    if (!valid) {
      champion[reached.valid].setCustomValidity("This is not a valid champion, please correct this field and resubmit.")
    }

    //Check for duplicates
    if (!unique) {
      champion[reached.unique].setCustomValidity("This champion has already been entered.")
    }

    this.checkValidity();
  };
});
```

Comment: If your code is not being executed when calling checkseason() but it is when you don't call it, it most likely means you have an uncaught exception inside checkseason.

Comment: Any errors shown in the console?

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't run? WHat troubleshooting steps have you tried?

Comment: Maybe `champions` is undefined? You define `champion` but not `champions`. Generally, [JSHint](http://jshint.com) helps.

Comment: there are no errors in console. And checkseason function runs fine but then the rest of the code doesnt and the other way around without checkseeason the rest of the code runs fine

Comment: @Higeath I think you can diagnose this yourself, by placing `console.log('0');`, `console.log('1');`, etc. throughout the sections in your main function and looking how far the code gets. That’s how I always do it. When something doesn’t get executed, you probably know, where the problem is.

Comment: alright for some reason this form gets attribute novalidate="novalidate" for some reason which causes this

Comment: the plugin does that to prevent browser html5 validation kicking in. WHy would that have any impact on your code?

Comment: @charlietfl I have no clue but after executing checkseason(); ive placed $('#second_form').removeAttr('novalidate'); and now it all works

Comment: huh...defeats the purpose of the plugin then  ...good luck

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't get any better answers though

Comment: well the higher level problem is still not clear is why. All you said was function is ignored...we can't see what is or isn't working properly. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: if (!valid) {
     console.log('5');
  champion[reached.valid].setCustomValidity("This is not a valid champion, please correct this field and resubmit.")
   console.log('6');
   }

   //Check for duplicates
   if (!unique) {
   
  champion[reached.unique].setCustomValidity("This champion has already been entered.")
   }
   console.log('7');
   this.checkValidity();
    console.log('8');
 };  

I've tried this and the code goes through as it should I'm not really sure how can I check where exactly is the problem